# Extract minutes per hour based on occupancy in Excel

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, timestamp, intervals

Is there an easy way to extract the minutes per hour a room  was used based on occupancy level? I would like to get an overview of how many minutes room 1 was used from 08:00:00- 08:59:59, 09:00:00-09:59:59..etc

I have done this manually by creating time intervals for every hour starting at fex 08:00:00 and ending at 08:59:59. Then I have used a sumif formula to get number of minutes the room was occupied per hour for one day (9 hours in total per day).

As I want to see how many minutes per hour different rooms are occupied and compare them, I wonder if there is an easier way to do this? It would be great to have a format that I could use for all rooms. However, since all rooms will have different timestamps, this might be difficult?

If anyone knows how to do this in SQL or Python, that would be very helpful as well, especially in SQL!

The link below will give you an example of the data.

[image: Example of what the data looks like]

Comment: Please include the data as text in your question. Working from an image is difficult and discouraged on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the most analogous data structure to a spreadsheet or a SQL table is the `DataFrame` from the `pandas` library.

First we can read in data from a spreadsheet like so:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("<your filename>", parse_dates=[1])

df["Time"] = df.Timestamp.dt.time
```

Here I am going to assume you have removed your work-in-progress (table on the right in the image) and that the data is in the first worksheet of the Excel file (otherwise we'll have to pass additional options).

I've ensured that the first (`Timestamp`) column is correctly understood as containing date-time data. By default it will assume `09.01.2020 ...` refers to the 1st of September, American-style - I'm *guessing* that's what you want; additional options can be passed if you were really referring to the 9th of January (which is how I'd read that date).

I then overwrote the `Time` column with a `time` object extracted from the `Timestamp`, this isn't really necessary but gets the data as close to what was in the spreadsheet as possible. The DataFrame now looks like this:

```
            Timestamp Room name  Occupancy %      Time
0 2020-09-01 08:04:01    Room 1            0  08:04:01
1 2020-09-01 09:04:01    Room 1          100  09:04:01
2 2020-09-01 09:19:57    Room 1            0  09:19:57
3 2020-09-01 09:48:57    Room 1            0  09:48:57
4 2020-09-01 09:53:01    Room 1          100  09:53:01
5 2020-09-01 10:05:01    Room 1          100  10:05:01
6 2020-09-01 10:08:57    Room 1          100  10:08:57
7 2020-09-01 10:13:01    Room 1          100  10:13:01
```

(Note for next time, it would have been good to include something like this text in your question, it makes it much easier to construct an answer if the data doesn't have to be painstakingly put together)

Now, there are a lot of things we can do with a DataFrame like this, but I'm going to try and get to where you want to go as directly as possible.

We'll start by using the Timestamp column as the 'index' and prepending a row for the time 08:00:00 because it's not currently part of your dataset, but you indicated you want it.

```py
df2 = df.set_index("Timestamp")

df2.loc[pd.Timestamp("09.01.2020 08:00:00")] = ("Room1", 0.0, None)

df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

The result looks like this:

```
                    Room name  Occupancy %      Time
Timestamp                                           
2020-09-01 08:00:00    Room 1          0.0      None
2020-09-01 08:04:01    Room 1          0.0  08:04:01
2020-09-01 09:04:01    Room 1        100.0  09:04:01
2020-09-01 09:19:57    Room 1          0.0  09:19:57
2020-09-01 09:48:57    Room 1          0.0  09:48:57
2020-09-01 09:53:01    Room 1        100.0  09:53:01
2020-09-01 10:05:01    Room 1        100.0  10:05:01
2020-09-01 10:08:57    Room 1        100.0  10:08:57
2020-09-01 10:13:01    Room 1        100.0  10:13:01
```

Now, the simplest way to do this is to start by upsampling and forward-filling the data.

```py
upsampled = df2.resample("1min").ffill()
```

`upsampled` is a huge DataFrame with a value for every second in the range. The forward-filling ensures your occupancy % is carried forward every second until one of your original datapoints said 'it changed here'. After the change, the new value is carried forward to the next datapoint etc.

This is done to ensure we get the necessary time resolution. Normally I would now downsample. You were interested in each hour:

```py
downsampled = upsampled.resample("1h").mean()
```

By taking the mean, we'll get only the numeric columns in our output, i.e. 'occupancy', and here you'll get the following:

```
                     Occupancy %
Timestamp                       
2020-09-01 08:00:00     0.000000
2020-09-01 09:00:00    38.194444
2020-09-01 10:00:00   100.000000
```

*But* you indicated you might want to do this 'per room', so there might be other data with e.g. 'Room 2'. In that case, we have a categorical column, `Room name`, that we need to group by.

This is a bit harder, because it means we have to group before we upsample, to avoid ambiguity. This is going to create a MultiIndex. We have to collapse the 'group' level of the index, *then* group and downsample!

```py
grouped = df.groupby("Room name", as_index=False).resample('1s').ffill()

grouped.index = grouped.index.get_level_values(1)

result = grouped.groupby("Room name").resample("1h").mean()
```

which will look something like this:

```
                               Occupancy %
Room name Timestamp                       
Room 1    2020-09-01 08:00:00     0.000000
          2020-09-01 09:00:00    38.194444
          2020-09-01 10:00:00   100.000000
Room 2    2020-09-01 08:00:00     0.000000
          2020-09-01 09:00:00    38.194444
          2020-09-01 10:00:00   100.000000
```

(I just duplicated the data for Room 1 as Room 2, so the numbers are the same)

For a neat finish, we might unstack this multi-index, pivoting the room names into columns. Then convert those percentages into the nearest number of minutes.

Thus the whole solution is:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("<your filename>", parse_dates=[1])

df2 = df.set_index("Timestamp")

# prepend some dummy rows for every different room name
for room_name in df2["Room name"].unique():
    df2.loc[pd.Timestamp("09.01.2020 08:00:00")] = (room_name, 0.0, None)


df2.sort_index(inplace=True)

grouped = df.groupby("Room name", as_index=False).resample('1s').ffill()

grouped.index = grouped.index.droplevel(0)

result = (
    grouped
        .groupby("Room name")
        .resample("1h")
        .mean()
        .unstack(level=0)
        .div(100)  # % -> fraction
        .mul(60)  # fraction -> minutes
        .astype(int)  # nearest number of whole minutes
)

# no longer 'Occupancy %', so drop the label
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
```

yielding a `result` like

```
Room name                Room 1 Room 2
Timestamp                             
2020-09-01 08:00:00           0      0
2020-09-01 09:00:00          22     22
2020-09-01 10:00:00          60     60
```

which hopefully is close to what you were after.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point:

```
SELECT
    room_name, sum(start-stop)
FROM 
    room_table
WHERE 
    timestamp BETWEEN 'some_time' AND 'another_time'
GROUP BY
    room_name
```

Where in the above the SQL table is `room_table`. Also assumes `start` and `stop` fields are `time` types. The 'some_time/another_time` are just placeholders for the time range you are interested in.